# Data is stuck in $http .then method

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi I am trying to display my data but when i tried to display it on my html using angular data wont pass through. checked the console and data was there. here is my html.

```
<ion-view view-title="">  
<ion-content>
   <!--  <div class="cards">
        <div class="item item-image">
            <img src="img/banner-children.jpg"></img>
        </div>
    </div> -->

    <div class="list card padding" ng-repeat="charity in charityList">
    <a href="#/app/charitypage/{{charity.charity_id}}" class="positive ">
    <img class="char-logo img-thumb" ng-src="{{charity.logo}}">
        <div class="char-info">
            <h3 class="char-name text-pink">
            <i class="ion-chevron-right text-pink btn-category"></i>
            {{charity.charity_name}}</h3>
            <p class="dark">{{charity.description}}</p>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>


</ion-content>
```

and here is my controller

angular.module('subCategory.controllers', [])
.controller('subCatCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http) {

```
$scope.getCategoryList = function(category){
  $scope.charityList = {};
    var categoryListData = {
      charityCategory :  category
    }
 $http({
          method: 'POST',
          header: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
          url: 'http://localhost/filantrome/Main/getCategoryList',
          data: categoryListData
        }).then(
        function success( response ) {

          $scope.charityList= response.data;                     
          console.log($scope.charityList);
             $state.go('app.subcat');
        },
        function error( response ) {
          $scope.charityList = response.data;
          console.log($scope.charityList);
          // handle error
        }
        );
       console.log($scope.charityList);
```

};

});

i can see the data that i was requesting on the console.log() inside the success function. but when i get out of the .then(); function $scope.charityList is empty.
what am i missing here? thanks!

Comment: your `console.log($scope.charityList);` statement executing before your `async` data comes, you can get the async data value inside `.then` functiom only

Comment: can u show me how to do it?

Comment: the way you did it is correct only..simply you can't get the `charityList` outside `.
then` function.

Comment: seems problem is in state change. You change state and scope changes to new states controller.

Comment: how can i take the data outside the .then function ?

Comment: provide router info with $stateProvider config and html name, please.

Comment: @MikeKor the html i posted above is the target for the $state.go. my problem is that data cant get out of the .then function :(

Comment: Can you paste the data you are seeing in the console?

Comment: then provide controller that matches this html and state 'app.subcat'

Comment: @Bilal 
object                                                subcatCtrl.js:19
0: Object
category: "children"
charity_address: "blablab"
charity_id: "1"
charity_name: "blablab"
description: "blablab"
featured_video: ""
mission: "To help street children."
password: "blablab"
username: "blabalba"
vision: "aw"

Comment: @MikeKor that's the controller for that html, the one i posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems problem is in state change. To fix this you can use service to store received JSON

```
angular.module('subCategory.controllers', []).service(charityService, charityService);


  /* @ngInject */
function charityService($http) {
  var charityList = [];

  var service = {
    getData: getData,
    getCharityList: getCharityList  
  };


  return service;

  function getCharityList() {
      return charityList ;
  }
  function getData(categoryListData) {
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      header: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      url: 'http://localhost/filantrome/Main/getCategoryList',
      data: categoryListData
    }).then(
    function success( response ) {

      charityList = response.data;                     
      console.log(charityList );

      $state.go('app.subcat'); // you can also change state here   
    },
    function error( response ) {
      $scope.charityList = response.data;
      console.log($scope.charityList);
      // handle error
    }
    );
  }

}
```

then post data with controller function

```
$scope.getCategoryList = function(category){
    var categoryListData = {
        charityCategory :  category
    }

    charityService.getData(categoryListData);        
}
```

after state changes controller will get charityList from service

```
angular.module('subCategory.controllers', []) .controller('subCatCtrl',
    function($scope, $state, $http, charityService) {
    $scope.charityList = charityService.getCharityList();

// ...
```

Comment: by the way for charityService.getData($scope.charityList); in the getCategoryList function it doesnt work.  so i changed it to

charityService.getData(categoryListData); and it worked fine! :D thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you have posted your `console.log` output, I can see that you have a single object receiving and assigning to `charityList` but you have an `ng-repeat` on the element. So, I think you should change `$scope.charityList = {};` to `$scope.charityList = [];` or you can output this variable in the html to see whats going on like `{{charityList}}`.